# How to parse redhat alert xml files with namesapce using perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-namespaces

I using perl to parse Redhat advisory files.  The files use namespace. I figured out how to define namespaces and get things extracted.  However, when I have two level deep of namespacing, I can not extract information. for example, I can not print the CVE value,
here is the xml file and my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cvrfdoc xmlns="http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1" > 
<Vulnerability Ordinal="1" xmlns="http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/vuln/1.1">
<CVE>CVE-2013-4162</CVE>
</Vulnerability>
<Vulnerability Ordinal="2" xmlns="http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/vuln/1.1">
<CVE>CVE-2013-4299</CVE>
</Vulnerability>
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;
use Data::Dumper;
     $file="/var/tmp/redhatAdvisories/xyz.xml";                                                                               

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("$file");
my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc);
$xc->registerNs('NSP', 'http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1');
$xc->registerNs('NSPV', 'http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/vuln/1.1');
my $cve ="";
my $releaseDate ="";
for my $vul ( $xc->findnodes('//NSP:cvrfdoc/NSPV:Vulnerability') ) {
 my $ord         = $vul->findvalue('@Ordinal');
 $cve=$vul->findnodes('CVE');
 print " Vul Ordinal: $ord,$cve\n";
}
```

Comment: the last two lines suppose to look like:  my $ord         = $vul->findvalue('@Ordinal');
 $cve=$vul->findvalue('CVE');

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.

First; keep using your `$xc` to find nodes. Don't call `$vul->findnodes`.

Second; note that the `<CVE>` elements *are* namespaced!

```
for my $vul ( $xc->findnodes('//NSP:cvrfdoc/NSPV:Vulnerability') ) {
    my $ord = $xc->findvalue('@Ordinal', $vul);
    $cve=$xc->findnodes('NSPV:CVE', $vul);
    print " Vul Ordinal: $ord,$cve\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I offer an alternate suggestion? Just ignore the namespaces, and parse it with `XML::Twig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );
foreach my $vuln ( $twig -> findnodes ( '//Vulnerability' ) )
{
    print $vuln -> att ( 'Ordinal' ), ' => ', $vuln -> first_child_text('CVE'),"\n";
}
```